# Request body fails to showup fop PUT method in JMeter version 3

Tags: json, jmeter

I am firing a simple HTTP Request for PUT method in JMeter with JSON body:

[image: JMeter HTTP Request]

Though the request successfully gets executed, JSON request body is not appearing in the Listener
[image: Viwe Result Tree - Response]

```
PUT data:
<actual file content, not shown here>
```

This issue is happening in Jmeter version 3.
It is totally fine in Jmeter version 2.13 where complete JSON body appears in the Request tab.

Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is an identified "bug":

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60092

It will be fixed for upcoming 3.1, you can try the patch attached to issue.

It's cause is this fix in 3.0:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58852

Patch has been merged, you can test nightly buuild:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: But I am not sure how to use the patch which is attached to the bug zila issue